# Performance impact- C# class with number of unused properties

Tags: c#, performance, class, data-structures

I've a class called **Clients**. It has around 15 fields. 
While listing the client details or Add/Update, all fields are utilized but there is a scenario in which I just need list of **ClientId** & **CompanyName**.

Assigning these two fields from database to class objects and then using list of class has any performance impact? What is better? Creating separate class for these two fields or is this okay if I use the class with 10-15 fields bbut only assign 2 fields which I want?

Answer (score 2):

> Assigning these two fields from database to class objects and then using list of class has any performance impact?

Well each instance you create will have those fields, and they will take up memory. Whether that's *significant* or not is a different matter. If you're only creating a few instances, it's probably irrelevant. If you're creating millions of instances and are running with limited memory, that could be a problem.

More importantly from my perspective, code that uses `Clients` (any reason it's not just `Client`, singular?) may not be aware that only those two properties are going to be populated. It may well be much more *readable* for you to create another class with just those properties. If you need to write code which can use either the "limited" or "full" versions, there are two options:

- Create an interface for both the "limited" and "full" versions to implement
- Make the "limited" version a base class for the "full" version

In both cases you'll get the quite-possibly-irrelevant performance benefit of not having a bunch of never-populated fields when you only need the limited version, but more importantly you can make it clear what information any particular piece of code really needs.